# Check duplicate value in string

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

i've string which contain value and I want to check if specific value is exist more than one time for example

```
"aaaa:123&bbbbb ccccc*fooo barr/bazzzz 123"
```

the string can contain sigh like : and & and /

there is a way to know for example if I have in this string the number 123 twice?

Im using underscore but can also use lodash if it required .

Comment: What would happen if the string had `12345`, `x123y`, or `612311` in it too? Would those count as instances of `123`?

Comment: @muistooshort - no I just want to check the exact key if I've 12345 and I put 123 I got it one time even for 612311 and x123y ...

Comment: So what counts as a delimiter? Why would the `123` in `:123&` count but the `123` in `x123y` not count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can traverse it manually to make it more efficient, but this works and is quite simple:

```
console.log(str.match(/123/g).length > 1);
```

To use a variable, you need to use a regExp:

```
var str =  "aaaa:123&bbbbb ccccc*fooo barr/bazzzz 123";
var v = "2";
var regex = new RegExp("1"+v+"3", "g");
var matches = str.match(regex);
console.log(matches != null && matches.length > 1) // matches will be null if there are no finds
```

Comment: Thanks and assume i want to put a parameters instead of /123/g how should I put it?

Comment: That regex will also find `x123y` and `612311` which may not be desired.

Comment: @muistooshort yeah depends on how the op wants it, but feel free to change the regex expression

Comment: @juvian- thanks but I need to use the value as dynamic value now its 123 but it can be any value like 456 so I cannot use ("1"+v+"3", "g");

Comment: @AlBundy it was just an example, you can just put your variable in string format as the first parameter. new RegExp(variable, "g");